# How to type value stored inside variable in text field?

Tags: autoit

Right now, I'm using this:

`Send (&varname)`

I saw some other way of doing it on the internet which made the process much faster, but I don't remember what it was.

Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [ControlSend](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) or even better [ControlSetText](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSetText.htm). Both links have examples on how to use them and are much better then using Send.

In most situations it is better to use ControlSend then Send because you want to make sure you are sending the text to the right window. If you can't access a windows control you can still use ControlSend without a Control name like so.

```
ControlSend($hWnd, "", "", "I am some text...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, in case your program does not utilize Windows API and has no classic 'Controls' to send text directly. For example, I have this .NET 4 program and AutoIt's window info utility can target only it's main window, all forms elements do not have any control ids.

```
ClipPut($text)
send("+{insert}")
```

Could work or not, depending on your specific program and data you need to insert in fields

Comment: I added an example on how to use ControlSend when can't access the controls ids.